# Event after a Outlook Appointment was saved

Tags: c#, .net, events, outlook-addin

I am writing an Outlook Add-in and want to do something (not relevant here) with the data of an Appointment after (when) it was saved.
(i am new to Outlook-Addins)
so i found that there is an *AfterWrite* event where i can register a Method.
And there is an *ItemLoad* event on *Application*.

so my first Efford was something like this:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    this.Application.ItemLoad += 
        new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(atItemLoad);
}
public void atItemLoad(Object item)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    if (aitem != null)
    {
        aitem.AfterWrite += 
            new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_AfterWriteEventHandler(afterWrite);
    }
}
public void afterWrite()
{
    // Who was written?
    MessageBox.Show("it was written!");
}
```

The problem is, that I don't know how to get to the data of the Appointment, that fired the event.
*Application.ItemLoad* registers a function that gets an Object, that can be cast to an *Appointment*.
*AfterWrite* does not. I'd like something like this:

```
public void afterWrite(Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem)
{
    // do something with the data from the Appointment
    MessageBox.Show(aitem.Subject + " was written!");
}
```

I fear that I am researching in the totally wrong direction..

*sorry if my english is a mess - it's not my mother language

edit:

i even tried a construct like this:

```
private List<AppointmentEventHolder> holderList = new List<AppointmentEventHolder>();

internal class AppointmentEventHolder
{
    private Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = null;
    public AppointmentEventHolder(Outlook.AppointmentItem item)
    {
        aitem = item;
    }

    public void onWrite()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("write: " + aitem.Subject);
    }
}

public void atItemLoad(Object item)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    if (aitem != null)
    {
        AppointmentEventHolder aHolder = new AppointmentEventHolder(aitem);
        holderList.Add(aHolder);
        aitem.AfterWrite += aHolder.onWrite;
    }
}
```

but event doesn't get fired!
i am very frustrated now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ok, i think i got this.
You have to register a handler on the Folder, that has your Appointments.

i read and experienced myself, that its crutial to save a reference to the objects you register an event, so i did this.
So thats the code

```
private Outlook.MAPIFolder _CalendarFolder = null;
private Outlook.Items _CalendarItems = null;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Outlook.MAPIFolder calendarFolder =
        this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

    // get the Termine24-Folder (if not found, create it)
    try
    {
        _CalendarFolder = calendarFolder.Folders[Constants.FOLDERNAME];
    }
    catch
    {
        _CalendarFolder = calendarFolder.Folders.Add(Constants.FOLDERNAME);
    }
    _CalendarItems = _CalendarFolder.Items;
    attachEvents();

}
public void attachEvents()
{
    _CalendarItems.ItemAdd += Item_Add;
    _CalendarItems.ItemChange += Item_Change;
    _CalendarItems.ItemRemove += Item_Remove;
}
public void Item_Add(Object item)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    if (aitem != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("add: " + aitem.Subject);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("add, but no appointment");
    }
}
public void Item_Change(Object item)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem aitem = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
    if (aitem != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("changed: " + aitem.Subject);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("change, but no appointment");
    }
}
public void Item_Remove()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item_remove");
}
```

to good thing is, that now I also get an event if the appointment gets drag-and-dropped in the overview.

BUT the Item_Remove still don't gets me the Object that got removed.

Comment: What is the "**Constants.FOLDERNAME**" that your C# code refers to ?

Without knowing what this constant refers to, I can't build your code.

Comment: `private MAPIFolder GetCalendarFolder()
{                                                                  var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
NameSpace nameSpace = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
return nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
}`                                                                       **Use this method to get the default Outlook.MAPIFolder object**

Comment: ItemRemove event cannot possible give you the item because at the time the event fires, the item is already gone. The best you an do is use Redemption and its RDOItems.ItemRemove event - it at least passes the value of the PR_INSTANCE_KEY property. Which you can use to look up the item's entry id etc. if you previously created a dictionary of  PR_INSTANCE_KEY vs some other property that you are interested in.